# String and Bool (Int Condition to be false) C++

Tags: c++, string

Im new to C++ and I tried searching but I have no idea on what to search. Sorry. My problem is:

1. When I set the bool condition false, it still requires me to input 2 x to terminate the compiler. Why is that so? (I tried using cin.fail () but it didnt work)
2. When I print the list of courses, it lists the one that should terminate the program (ie when you press x). How do I correct this?
   Thank you for your help.

   ```
    int main(void)
   {
   // Gather list of courses and their codes from user,
   // storing data as a vector of strings
   const string DegreeCode("PHYS");
   string CourseTitle;
   int CourseCode(0);
   vector <string> CourseList;
   vector <string> :: iterator iter;

     bool not_finished(true);
    do
   {
   if (CourseTitle == "x" && "X")
   {
       not_finished=false;
   }
   else
   {
       cout<<"Please enter a course code and a course title (or x to finish): "<<endl;
       cin>>CourseCode;
       cin.sync();
       cin.clear();
       getline(cin , CourseTitle);

       ostringstream oss;
       string outputCourseList (oss.str ());

       oss  << DegreeCode << " " << CourseCode << " "<< CourseTitle;



       CourseList.push_back (oss.str ());
       cout <<outputCourseList <<endl;
       oss.str("");    //clear oss content
   }

     } while(not_finished);

         // Print out full list of courses
           cout<<"List of courses:\n"<<endl;
          for (iter = CourseList.begin(); iter != CourseList.end(); iter++)
           cout<<(*iter)<<endl;

            return 0;
               }
   ```

Comment: Why is your indentation so bizarre?

Comment: I think it's because when I copy paste the code in the web to submit it, some of them are not within it, so I have to manually indent them. That's why they are bizarre.

Comment: You can manually indent them better

Answer (score 1):

```
if (CourseTitle == "x" && "X")
{
    not_finished=false;
}
```

to

```
if (strcmp(CourseTitle.c_str(), "x") == 0 || strcmp(CourseTitle.c_str(), "X") == 0)
{
    not_finished=false;
}
```

== is a pointer comparison, almost never true... "x" == "x" will even be false unless you're good with compiler flags

Make sure to

```
#include <string.h> //<----.h is needed!
```

Comment: He's using std::string so == is fine. Just not the logic. Can use compare() or == (which uses compare).

Comment: The problem is that he is using the string class.. Teaching him how to do it correctly now will save him a lot later when he upgrades to C or assembly.

Comment: The problem is the `&& "X"` part.  The `"X"` always evaluates to `true`.  The expression should be `((CourseTitle == "x") || (CourseTitle == "X"))

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is your comparison in the `if` statement:

```
if (CourseTitle == "x" && "X")
```

The proper syntax is: (variable operator variable) && (variable operator variable)

The syntax corrected:

```
if ((CourseTitle == "x") && (CourseTitle == "X"))
```

There is a logic issue because a variable can't equal two values at the same time.

Maybe you want:

```
if ((CourseTitle == "x") || (CourseTitle == "X"))
```

which means one **OR** the expressions is true.

You could eliminate the two compares by **transforming** the string into all uppercase or all lowercase.  Search the web for "C++ string transform tolower toupper".